# How to create a button that leads to another page that I have created?

Tags: html, css

I have created 2 pages with CSS and HTML and now I want to link the two together.

I found this code, but I am sure there are better options:

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
</form>
```

If I use this, do I have to upload both pages to the internet? How can I link my two pages together?

Comment: Why not use a link?

Comment: You should use a link for such a thing. It's more semantic. `<a href="http://google.com">Go to Google</a>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: use <a> tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: _"if I use this I have to upload both pages to the internet, right?"_ - You need a webhost/webserver and a registered domain linked via DNS record @yourFavoriteProviderAndRegistrar, then upload it and hope you don't break the whole the internet ;) On as serious note - make yourself familiar with frontend-development and the whole www first before jumping right into the middle, it's important to now the basics!

Comment: You don't need to upload the pages at all. If you do this on your local machine, just make sure to add the file-path instead of an URL

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<a href="http://google.com">Go to Googl</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna stick to your Form approach, see below:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com">
  <button type="submit" class="">Go to Google</button>
</form>
```

more elegant is this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
 <input type="button" value="Go to Google" />
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, It will help you to learn HTML & Bootstrap

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click Here</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need Bootstrap to link two pages together.